# Проблема с remove в RecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня есть `RecyclerView`, заполненный `View`. Мне нужно удалять элементы, при долгом нажатии, что я и пытаюсь сделать.

Вот адаптер (не весь, остальное не нужно):

```
public class CustomListAdapter_Words extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomListAdapter_Words.ViewHolder> {
    private CreatePage_Fragment mFragment;

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mWordsForm_1;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View v;

        TextView textView_1_form_1;
        TextView textView_2_form_1;
        TextView textView_3_form_1;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.textView_1_form_1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
            this.textView_2_form_1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
            this.textView_3_form_1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_3);

            this.v = view;
        }
    }


        public CustomListAdapter_Words(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> wordsForm_1, CreatePage_Fragment fragment) {
            mFragment = fragment;
            mWordsForm_1 = wordsForm_1;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            ViewHolder myViewHolder;

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_words_form_1, parent, false);
            myViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

            return myViewHolder;
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {
            holder.textView_1_form_1.setText(mWordsForm_1.get(listPosition).get(0));
            holder.textView_2_form_1.setText(mWordsForm_1.get(listPosition).get(1));
            holder.textView_3_form_1.setText(mWordsForm_1.get(listPosition).get(2));

            holder.v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    mFragment.onLongClicked(listPosition, 1, mWordsForm_1, listPosition);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

При нажатии пункт списка передает свою позицию в списке, `List` и позицию в `ArrayList` (пусть позиции совпадают, но так нужно):

```
holder.v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mFragment.onLongClicked(listPosition, mWordsForm_1, listPosition);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Вот метод, который реализует удаление:

```
  public void onLongClicked(int position, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list, int positionInList) {
      listWithRecord.remove(position);
      ((CustomListAdapter_Words) adapter).notifyItemRemoved(position);
  }
```

Проблема в том, что первое удаление происходит успешно. Все удаляется правильно, но потом `RecyclerView` изменяет у всех `View` номера позиций в списке. `View` которые на экране не перезагружаются и, если удалять одно `View`, удаляется другое (больше на столько, сколько элементов я удалил). Чтобы было понятнее:

У меня есть три элемента (первый столбик — позиция в списке):

```
1 - персик (говорит, что первый в списке)
2 - абрикос (говорит, что второй в списке)
3 - слива (говорит, что третья в списке)
```

Если удалить первый элемент, получается так:

```
1 - абрикос (говорит, что второй в списке)
2 - слива (говорит, что третья в списке)
```

В результате удаления первого элемент, удаляется второй, а, в результате удаление второго — пишет, что я обращаюсь к несуществующему индексу списка.

Вопрос: как исправить это ошибку? Как через слушатель нажатия возвращать действительную позицию в списке?

Comment: У вас очепятка или вы какой--то внешней переменной пользуетесь? `positionInRecycler` & `positionInList`

Comment: Да и `listWithRecord` & `list` там же.

Comment: И что, если вы прямо из адаптера это делать будете?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не опечатка, просто использовал публичные переменные. Долго объяснять, но я исправил :). Удалять из фрагмента, а в фрагмент передавать позицию.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, но если нужно через адаптер - сделаю через адаптер! Мне нужны все варианты решения этой проблемы...

Comment: Можно по всякому... Кажется у вас просто не из того списка удаление идёт... Попробуйте прямо в адаптере из списка адаптера удалять.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, это ничего не даст. Но есть хорошая новость, я придумал, как это исправить! Я единственный человек, который три часа смотрит в монитор, а потом в душе придумывает алгоритм за 5 минут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у ViewHolder есть метод getAdapterPosition()

```
holder.v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mFragment.onLongClicked(getAdapterPosition(), mWordsForm_1);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

А long click ставить вот так:

```
      public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener {
                View v;

                TextView textView_1_form_1;
                TextView textView_2_form_1;
                TextView textView_3_form_1;

                public ViewHolder(View view) {
                    super(view);
                    view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
                    this.textView_1_form_1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_1);
                    this.textView_2_form_1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_2);
                    this.textView_3_form_1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_3);

                this.v = view;

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    mFragment.onLongClicked(getAdapterPosition(), mWordsForm_1);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Помог метод `getAdapterPosition()`! Пусть объявить слушатель в холдере не вышло (он статический, а фрагмент — нет), но я заменил `listPosition` на `getAdapterPosition` и все прекрасно заработало!